# How to find a specific xpath td class from a table with lxml and python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to use Python lxml to import a list of text from a page.
Here is what I have so far.

test_page.html source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr><td><a title="This page is cool" class="producttitlelink" href="about:mozilla">This page is cool</a></td></tr>
    <tr height="10"></tr>
    <tr><td class="plaintext">This is a really cool description for my really cool page.</td></tr>

            <tr><td class="plaintext">Published: 7/15/15</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="plaintext">



    </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="plaintext">


    </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="plaintext">


    </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="plaintext">

    </td></tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Python code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1/test_page.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
description = tree.xpath('//table//td[@class="plaintext"]/text()')
>> print (description)
['This is a really cool description for my really cool page.', 'Published: 7/15/15', '\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\n\t']
>>
```

However the desired end-result is:

```
['This is a really cool description for my really cool page. Published: 7/15/15']
```

I had thought that using [1] -

```
tree.xpath('//table//td[@class="plaintext"][1]/text()')
```

might allow me to receive the first line:

```
['This is a really cool description for my really cool page.']
```

However it pulls the entire list.

Is there a way to specify a single line or list of lines using only an xpath for this html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
from lxml import html

source = """html posted in the question here"""
tree = html.fromstring(source)
tds = tree.xpath('//table//td[@class="plaintext"]/text()[normalize-space()]')
description = ' '.join(tds)
print(description)
```

the XPath predicate`[normalize-space()]` applied to `text()` will return only those non-whitespace text nodes.

Using the HTML posted in question, output of the above codes is exactly as requested :

```
This is a really cool description for my really cool page. Published: 7/15/15
```

Answer (score 0):

normalize-space() great solution, I don't know about it, but IRL better something like this:

```
' '.join([col.strip() for col in tree.xpath('//table//td[@class="plaintext"]/text()') if col.strip()])
```

it's strip realy all empty cells